# FLUSH TABLE : can't execute the given command because you have active locked tables mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, locking

If I execute these queries one by one, all fail except the first:

**Query1 :**

```
flush table tablename1 with read lock;
```

Works

**Query2 :**

```
flush table tablename2 with read lock;
```

> Error :  can't execute the given command because you have active locked tables mysql

If I execute, in below way, it works:

Query:

```
flush table tablename1,tablename2 with read lock;
```

What's happening inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because

```
flush table tablename1,tablename2 with read lock;
```

is contained within one transaction and

```
flush table tablename1 with read lock;

flush table tablename2 with read lock;
```

Is not.

In this second scenario the first table is locked for that session. That session can't acquire a second lock on another table because the session already has one table open. If you tried to access another different table by using a SELECT, **within that same session**, for example tablename2, that would also be refused.

```
MySQL [testlocks]> select * from tablename2;
ERROR 1100 (HY000): Table 'tablename2' was not locked with LOCK TABLES
```

So to make a long story short, by locking only one table you are saying that the current session only has access to that one table. At least that's how I understand MySQL's documentation.

Or you could just use

```
flush table tablename1,tablename2 with read lock;
```

as you already figured out and this is the syntax given by MySQL's documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html)

Comment: so is this a mysql bug ?

Comment: @user21546, definitely not a bug. The use of table lock is well documented and they have syntax for flush tables that works with using multiple tables.

Comment: but this doesnt happen with other databases like MSSQL.
Well , thank you so much @craig

Comment: @user21546. You're welcome. In my opinion, when MySQL is so specific in its documentation about a feature, its because the behavior was intended

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html), all locks in a session have to be obtained in a single statement.

> A session that requires locks must acquire all the locks that it needs in a single LOCK TABLES statement. While the locks thus obtained are held, the session can access only the locked tables